# How to use nuxt hooks in a module?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I define my own module and register it in nuxt.config.js. How do I use hooks in the module?

I've tried to do this as the documentation says https://nuxtjs.org/guide/modules (see bottom of the page) but the hooks don't seem to be firing.

```
module.exports = function () {

  console.log('hello from modules');

  this.nuxt.hook('module', moduleContainer => {
    console.log('modules!!!');
  });

  this.nuxt.hook('renderer', (renderer) => {
    console.log('renderer created');

    renderer.hook('render:done', (render) => {
      console.log('renderer done');
    });

  });
};
```

The module is loading ('hello from modules') but none of the hooks are firing.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

These are the corresponding documentations:

- https://nuxtjs.org/api/internals-builder
- https://nuxtjs.org/api/internals-renderer
- https://nuxtjs.org/api/internals-generator

Based on these, nuxt hooks can be used as:

```
export default function() {
    console.log("hello from modules");

    this.nuxt.hook("modules:before", (moduleContainer, options) => {
        console.log("modules:before");
    });
    // or
    this.nuxt.hook("modules:done", moduleContainer => {
        console.log("modules:done");
    });

    this.nuxt.hook("render:before", (renderer, options) => {
        console.log("render:before");
    });
    // or
    this.nuxt.hook("render:done", renderer => {
        console.log("render:done");
    });
    // or
    this.nuxt.hook("render:route", (url, result, context) => {
        console.log("render:route");
    });
};
```